# Find ratio of flags for every associated id from table_a.canon_id using mysql joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

```
table_a
user_id  canon_id  ratio (count of 1 / total)
1        1000      0.33
2        1000      0.33
3        1000      0.33
11       4344      0.50
88       4344      0.50
7        2023      0
8        2023      0
10       2023      0
12       3333      0.80
17       3333      0.80
18       3333      0.80
19       3333      0.80
20       3333      0.80

table_b
user_id  flag
1        0
2        0
3        1
11       1
88       0
14       0
7        1
8        1
10       1
12       1
17       1
18       1
19       1
20       0
```

In the above case, how can I join tables and populate the table_a.ratio by using flags from another MySQL table? the formula for ratio is (count of 1 / total user_ids associated with that canon_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions. `avg()` comes to mind:

```
select a.*, avg(b.flag) over(partition by a.canon_id) ratio
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.user_id = a.user_id
```

In earlier versions, a correlated subquery might be an acceptable solution:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (
        select avg(b1.flag) 
        from table_a a1 
        left join table_b b1 on b1.user_id = b.user_id
        where a1.canon_id = a.canon_id
    ) ratio
from table_a a
```